# counting the number of common sets in two files

Tags: python, awk, match

I would like to get your help in writing a script to count number of common set of numbers in two files. My files have format as shown below,

**File 1**

```
0: 152 145 148
1: 251 280 428
2: 42 281 407
3: 289 292 331
4: 309 212 226
5: 339 336 376
6: 339 376 380
7: 41 406 205
8: 237 418 193
```

**File 2**

```
0: 251 280 428
1: 309 212 226
2: 339 336 376
3: 339 376 380
4: 420 414 199
5: 418 193 237
6: 203 195 200
7: 287 161 257
8: 287 257 158
9: 263 369 15
10: 285 323 327
```

First column is just the serial numbers and should be ignored while checking the match between two files and set of same numbers with different ordering should be counted as common one `(for e.g 237 418 193 = 418 193 237)`

In this case, expected outcome will be.....

```
5 # no. of common sets
251 280 428
309 212 226
339 336 376
339 376 380
237 418 193
```

I have tried with an awk script -

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$3]=$0;next}{if(b=a[$3]){print b}}' file1 file2
```

Unfortunately, the set "237 418 193" didn't count since it have different ordering in the second file (418 193 237).

Can any help me to do this task with a `awk` or `Python` script.

Any help is appreciated?

Comment: The trick is to sort every set by increasing values to standardize the order.

Comment: I wrote a script a while ago to help me work with lines of a file as sets. The code is at https://github.com/nibrahim/lines. It sounds like you might be able to use it after some preprocessing (losing the serial numbers).

Answer (score 1):

Parse the file, creating a `set` of lines, each element sorted lexicographically.

```
file1_sets = {tuple(sorted(line.split()[1:])) for line in open(file1, 'r')}
file2_sets = {tuple(sorted(line.split()[1:])) for line in open(file2, 'r')}
```

Then see how many of one exist in the other

```
count = sum([f in file2_sets for f in file1_sets])
```

(Edited per comments)

Comment: You should not include the ids (first column of the files) in your sets

Comment: Yo have unneeded additions here - __f in file2_sets for f in file1_sets__ will do the job

Comment: @volcano, brilliant, thank you! I love how your change mostly just rearranged the words that were already there.

Comment: @mhlester, I just used the fact that integer values of True and False are 1 and 0 respectively. Glad to help

Answer (score 0):

Try this python code:

```
data1, data2 = [], []
for fname, data in [('file1.txt', data1), ('file2.txt', data2)]:
    for line in open(fname):
        data.append(set(line.strip().split()[1:]))

common = [s for s in data1 if s in data2]
for c in common:
    print c
print len(common)
```

Output:

```
set(['280', '251', '428'])
set(['309', '212', '226'])
set(['336', '339', '376'])
set(['380', '339', '376'])
set(['237', '418', '193'])
5
```

Answer (score 0):

Using sets and `.intersection`:

```
with open("21132195_1.txt") as fh1, open("21132195_2.txt") as fh2:
    number_sets1 = set(frozenset(line.split()[1:]) for line in fh1)
    number_sets2 = set(frozenset(line.split()[1:]) for line in fh2)

common_number_sets = number_sets1.intersection(number_sets2)

print "%i # no. of common sets" % len(common_number_sets)
print "\n".join([" ".join(s) for s in common_number_sets])
```

Will give as output:

```
5 # no. of common sets
339 376 380
251 280 428
212 226 309
193 237 418
336 339 376
```

Comment: I am just curious - why to you need calls to _sorted_ and _tuple_?

Comment: `sorted` is needed to make all lines sorted ascending and to handle different ordering of numbers. `tuple` is needed as only hashable objects can be used in sets - and the resulting `list` is not hashable.

Comment: Just one correction - I was thinking of set of sets - and I've forgotten that _set_ is not hashable. But there is hashable _frozenset_, so _frozenset(line.split()[1:])_. It is a little bit more readable than wrapping 2 function calls - and its is more efficent. Used over _file1_ as list of strings, it worked about 30% faster

Answer (score 0):

In Gnu Awk version 4.1, you can use `PROCINFO["sorted_in"]` like:

```
gawk -f  c.awk file1 file2
```

where `c.awk` is:

```
BEGIN {PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@val_num_asc"}
NR==FNR {
    b[getRow()]++
    next
}
{
    c=getRow()
    if (c in b)
        a[++j]=c
}
END{
    print j" # no. of common sets"
    for (i in a) 
        print a[i]
}

function getRow(b,d,i) {
    for (i=2; i<=NF; i++)
        d[i]=$i
    for (i in d)
        b=(b=="")?d[i]:(b" "d[i])
    return b
}
```

Output:

```
5 # no. of common sets
193 237 418
212 226 309
251 280 428
336 339 376
339 376 380
```

Comment: thank for the help. But when I used for a different input files ( with a similar file format as earlier), the program gives a wrong output. It suppose to find 7 common sets, but the output shows only 5 of them.

Comment: @user3138998 Can you paste the input files at http://pastebin.com/ ? Then I will check it out..

Answer (score 0):

Another way using shell.

```
cat file1 file2 |while read x line  
do 
   arr2=($(for val in $line;do echo "$val";done|sort -n))
   echo "${arr2[@]}"
done|awk '++a[$1,$2,$3]>1'

251 280 428
212 226 309
336 339 376
339 376 380
193 237 418
```